# Vuejs3 pass props to slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a problem I'm stuck on right now, which has been bothering me for a few days right now, but I couldn't find a reasonable solution. I'm not even sure if it's possible at all.

What exactly I have in mind: I want to pass properties via  to the child components. However, I want to do this without specifying the scope in the parent, like this:

```
<MyComponent v-slot="foobar">
  <MySub :text="foobar.text" />
  <MySub :text="foobar.text" />
  <MySub :text="foobar.text" />
</MyComponent>
```

Since these components always occur together, so i would like to make the code cleaner for useability reasons. What I have tried (This is not meant to be working code, but just to illustrate what I want to achieve): [Playground Sample](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqNUsFugzAM/RUrFzapkDtik6ade9puyw5pMZQKkigJrBPqv8+BgiirukkcbMd+fs+Pnr0Yk3QtspRlbm8r45+FqhqjrYft96umSKHyUFjdQJTwRS2MRYvmt3a3aKPs0gAgFJ6GphwL2dYe+lDdT0AuHQuw3LiZKgQUwrNQ9GV8JkmJx8bU0mPIfLYYpkIYplIgxf+RZktlVMn4DM42bNQYN9IkR6cVHWsgLC4PTrBZgmCkOuSCHbw3LuXcFftwiqNLtC05RYltla8aTNA18c7qL4eWgAW7iB4wOBU7tLFFlaNFew9z1foLdzogSVkZeOX7LZdy6eXD46TOom+tmjKA0iL6SpVbdE6WmEJ0kHWt4R2dH6wf9t53D7rY1do/CVZovZMkdHQkr7ohIGvDO6QeT6FrtZPaCZcaxr+Aj2PX/s2/459yjdV0X/iIwrLo8x7tic/IOgnZmjpA30N4gDPh3GZ3/gGw1zdY)

I also tried hacks like:

```
this.$slots.default().forEach((x) => {x.props.text = 'newText'})
```

But this seems to be most worst hack i could use (if it still would work :D ).

Hope somebody can help me. Codesamples in Playground:

[The "normal" working way](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqlU01v2zAM/SuCMEApkFh3wy1Q9NzTdpt2UGLGdmFLBkW7HYL891FK/NG0wzYMMGyRenoiH59P8rHvs3EAmcsiHLDp6cG4pus9knj++eR55cCROKLvhMr0KhePqRX467BfwTi6AoQwDt4SqISjHVoSp5g9TEQhvyTE+sbtlGGiuDwbx0+h5yI5IOj61hLEiIp1ueMutJ7ujTx6v7doJEMiHYNimTnB27KbxchI/deYYi0DZwo9VyK38iLIrrN99hK8Y2VTd+a6EYyc+zWSJYqxkTVRH3Ktw/EQdXsJmcdK8yrDwVHTQQah2+3RvwZAJjbyqlDi0JwcAXcIrgQEbvj3nDfQD7yT2tzKzbTfmeSzkZaW7OZu6g6BBnRTJESFANS46hlCsBXkQtW2bb34BoGST9K9/EqdHRBY0HKho7oJ2RfvNmq07QBPtXUVlGorGHL/sFxjW0DaqEcXO1J3V+L0/YOJeLJlM6YF+yk6aHbBTe1sKGZhwMV6+nLsvQ/mf+A/ZUvdsljWhVdu6INQPXqesviuYqnqR8p1QLUvlx9rrdhy06QpdA0LNmEql1RNWyk3SfhvCgpxOolYkjjzic9FOv8CtcOF7A==)

[What i want to achieve](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNqNUsFugzAM/RUrFzapkDtik6ade9puyw5pMZQKkigJrBPqv8+BgiirukkcbMd+fs+Pnr0Yk3QtspRlbm8r45+FqhqjrYft96umSKHyUFjdQJTwRS2MRYvmt3a3aKPs0gAgFJ6GphwL2dYe+lDdT0AuHQuw3LiZKgQUwrNQ9GV8JkmJx8bU0mPIfLYYpkIYplIgxf+RZktlVMn4DM42bNQYN9IkR6cVHWsgLC4PTrBZgmCkOuSCHbw3LuXcFftwiqNLtC05RYltla8aTNA18c7qL4eWgAW7iB4wOBU7tLFFlaNFew9z1foLdzogSVkZeOX7LZdy6eXD46TOom+tmjKA0iL6SpVbdE6WmEJ0kHWt4R2dH6wf9t53D7rY1do/CVZovZMkdHQkr7ohIGvDO6QeT6FrtZPaCZcaxr+Aj2PX/s2/459yjdV0X/iIwrLo8x7tic/IOgnZmjpA30N4gDPh3GZ3/gGw1zdY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like the kind of thing that could be solved with `provide/inject`

docs:
https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

example:

#### MyComponent.vue

```html
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        greetingMessage: 'hallo Test'
      }
    },
    provide(){
      return {greetingMessage: this.greetingMessage}
    }
  }
</script>

<template v-slot="foobar">
  <div>
    <slot :text="greetingMessage"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

#### MySub.vue

```html
<script>
  import {inject} from "vue"
  export default {
    inject: ['greetingMessage'],
  }
</script>

<template :text="foobar.text">
  <div>
    {{ greetingMessage }}
  </div>
</template>
```

This will make the value defined in `provide` available to any child (no matter how deep) through `inject`.

However not that the `provide` does not include reactivity out-of-the-box, so if you are expecting that to be reactive, just wrap in a computed (using composition api)

#### MyComponent.vue

```html
<script>
  import {computed} from "vue"
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        greetingMessage: 'hallo Test'
      }
    },
    provide(){
      return {greetingMessage: computed(()=>this.greetingMessage)}
    }
  }
</script>

<template v-slot="foobar">
  <div>
    <slot :text="greetingMessage"></slot>
    <button @click="greetingMessage = greetingMessage+'!'">
      change message
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

[link](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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) to working example on sfc

Comment: Sorry for my late feedback. But, back to topic.
Thank you!! Never worked with provide / inject in vue before. That does the trick, though the injection not limited to exact these two components. But in my situation, that is not a problem at all. The "MySub" is always the lowest component level.

My code looks like a little bit different now. I have tried to be type save due to typescript. But should do the same: 

`data() {
  return {
    groupId: inject('groupId') as number
  }
}`

In addition the case to set `app.config.unwrapInjectedRef = true` is also a little bit confusing.